# Change bitmap of a map marker

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to change the icon of an existing map marker in Google Maps Android API v2? I want to highlight the marker after the user clicks on it.

Comment: I think that the only way to do that is to remove the old `Marker` and put in a new one.

Comment: That's how I'll probably do it.

Comment: Marker has a new function added as of rev.7 of API v2. See [Marker.setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setIcon%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest Google Play Services (rev7), you can highlight a marker by swapping in a different icon using the `setIcon` method.

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
           .fromResource(R.drawable.highlighted_pin)); 
   }
});
```

... and I just now noticed *MaciejGórski*'s comment ....